# CasperJS to login to LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api, casperjs

I am using this code to login to LinkedIn using casperJS but its not working, the title after login should be "Welcome! LinkedIn" but its returning "World's Largest Professional Network | LinkedIn" and the document.location should be different than website url but its returning website url after execution.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({   
verbose: true, 
logLevel: 'debug',
pageSettings: {
     loadImages:  false,         // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
     loadPlugins: false,         // use these settings
     userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
}
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

var url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/';

casper.start(url, function() {
   // search for 'casperjs' from google form
   console.log("page loaded");
   this.test.assertExists('form#login', 'form is found');
   this.fill('form#login', { 
        session_key: 'username@gmail.com', 
        session_password:  'password'
    }, true);
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
   console.log("Page Title " + document.title);
   console.log("Your name is " + document.location ); 
});

casper.run();
```

What am I doing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the script evaluate the code too fast.

So i'll replace casper.thenEvaluate with this sentences (if you are running your script with casper 1.1) :

```
 casper.waitForUrl(/nhome/, function() {
      this.evaluate(function() {
          console.log("Page Title " + document.title);
          console.log("Your name is " + document.location ); 
      });
 });
```

Also, you can try it with wait

```
 casper.wait(2000, function() {
      this.evaluate(function() {
          console.log("Page Title " + document.title);
          console.log("Your name is " + document.location ); 
      });
 });
```

More information about this function : 
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforurl

Comment: Did you test the code you posted? I am getting this error `[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
`

Comment: Yeah and it works, but i'm french so maybe linkedin don't serve me the same page URL. Try with wait(2000, function() {});

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just archived this when I did something like this:

```
this.evaluate(function() {
    $('#login-email').val('EMAIL@mail.co');
    $('#login-email').focus();
});

this.page.sendEvent('keypress', this.page.event.key.M, null, null, 0x02000000);
this.capture('p1.1.png');

this.evaluate(function() {
    $('#login-password').val('PASSWORD');
    $('#login-password').focus();
});

//change to the last character of your password.
this.page.sendEvent('keypress', this.page.event.key[3]); 

this.page.sendEvent('keypress', this.page.event.key.Enter);
this.page.sendEvent('keypress', this.page.event.key.Enter);
```

I believe they don't enable the submit until you don't input something in the textfield.